# How should I maintain state between requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a web application that contains a sequence of views which will allow the user to submit different pieces of data which will have to be submitted to a 3rd party web service on completion.

e.g

> [Select Account Type] --> [Submit User Info] --> [Submit Billing
>   Details]

Each view is generated under a different Controller.

What is the best way to store the data between different views? As MVC is stateless, I can't just store it all in a global object until I'm ready to submit to the web service, and I think a database is overkill because I don't want to store the data any longer than it takes to submit all of it.

What is the best way to store the data until the end of the session, without e.g. storing it in the `Session` object?

Comment: @binncheol Any update on how you solved your problem?

Comment: @oliver I ended up using Session variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to store the user data is in session. as session is a data dictionary held by server across application against per user session. so any activity done by user including user details must be store in session, this will allow you to access the user object any where in the application across different views controller actions.

MVC gives you advantage to use Model Binding technique, which allows you access session variable in different controller's action across application.

for example on login .....

1. Store user in session
2. create model binder
3. register in global.asax
4. access it anywhere in across the application like simple parameter.
5. enjoy

*********************Login Controller********************

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    //store use object in session once
    Session["UserProfile"] = user;
}
```

*******************Create Model Binder**************************

```
 public class UserModelBinder:IModelBinder
    {
         private const string sessionKey = "UserProfile";

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
            ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {

            // get the Cart from the session 
                EntityUserProfile User = (EntityUserProfile)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
            // create the Cart if there wasn't one in the session data
                if (User == null){
                    User = new EntityUserProfile();
                    controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = User;
            }
            // return the cart
                return User;
        }
    }
```

*******************Register Model binder in global.asax***************

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(EntityUserProfile), new UserModelBinder()); 
        }
```

********************Access model binder any where in application **************
//following is 2nd paramter using model binder in one of my controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EmailWorkOrderInvoiceToClient(string OrderNumber, EntityUserProfile user)
 {
      // following is the user object from the session using model binder..
      var myuser=user;
 }
```

Comment: I agree that session should be used but in this case the use of a model binder seems overkill. Why not just pull the session data directly out of session whenever you need it rather than making it a parameter on the action method?

Comment: you can do that way..but you have to manually read, access and check the state of session variable every time. however this way 1 time configuration set-up would gives you advantage to control the session variable request in 1 place and use it anywhere with no hassle..

Answer (score 2):

Keeping true to **MVC**

I would recommend having these linked views in the same controller.  You could then easily persist your earlier model data in your later models.

For example, your `SubmitBillingDetailsModel` model could have a `SubmitUserInfoModel` property etc.

E.g:

```
public ActionResult SubmitUserInfo (SubmitUserInfoModel model)
{
    return View ("SubmitBillingDetails", new SubmitBillingDetailsModel
        {
            SubmitUserInfoModel = model
        });
}
```

You could even use one model to represent all separate views and cumulate the posted values between the separate views.

E.g:

```
public ActionResult SelectAccountType (CompleteModel model)
{
    return View ("SubmitBillingDetails", model);
}
```

**Just make sure that you persist the all values in your later views using hidden fields (maybe make a partial to do this for the whole model).**

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript localStorage proivided it is key/value pairs in strings